# Understanding the value that loop variable takes when increasing exponentially

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know that the time complexity of the loop having exponentially increasing loop variable is O(log(log(n))).

In the following code, i take values 2, 2^k, (2^k)^k = 2^k^2, (2^k^2)^k = 2^k^3, …, 2^k^logk(log(n)). The last term must be less than or equal to n, and we have 2^k^logk(log(n)) = 2^log(n) = n.

```
for (int i = 2; i <=n; i = pow(i, k))  
{
    // some O(1) expressions or statements
}
```

I'm not getting how does the final value of i become 2^k^logk(log(n))? How does the sequence get this general value mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's modify the code to explicitly track the number of iterations with another variable `j`:

```
for (int i = 2, j=0; i <=n; j+=1, i = pow(i, k))
```

Also let's assume that on some step the condition `i` exactly equals to `n`. That will be the last iteration. What the value of `j` will be at that step?

We can see that over iterations `i` is always

```
i = 2^(k^j)
```

so at that step

```
n = 2^(k^j)
```

To get `j` from that let's first apply `log2` to both sides:

```
log2(n) = k^j
```

and then apply `logk` (i.e. `log` with base `k`) to both sides:

```
j = logk(log2(n))
```

Obviously exact match `i == n` is a rare case but its absence only affects the total number of iterations by `1` which does not affect big-O. In other words, the last value of `i` does not become exactly `2^(k^logk(log2(n)))` i.e. `n`. It becomes something like `2^(k^logk(floor(log2(n))))` but asymptotically it is the same thing.